# Assigning permissions to multiple endpoints for a user and company

Tags: python

#### origin code:

```
# add this class to make the code can be a reproducible example.In acutually environment all attribute could be True or False.
class Capabilities:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.canEditCompany = True
        self.canDeleteCompany = True
        self.canShareCompany = True
        self.canAddFiscal = True
        self.canAddCategory = True
        self.canEditCategory = True
        self.canGetCategory = True
        self.canAddAccount = True
        self.canGetAccount = True
        self.canEditAccount = True
        self.canAddTransaction = True
        self.canAddScan = True
        self.canAddTax = True

def permission_control(user_email,company):
    capabilities = Capabilities()
    casbin_roles = []
    if capabilities.canEditCompany:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, company, 'PUT'))
    if capabilities.canDeleteCompany:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, company, 'Delete'))
    if capabilities.canShareCompany:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/sharing', 'Post'))
    if capabilities.canAddFiscal:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscal_year', 'POST'))
    if capabilities.canAddCategory:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'Post'))
    if capabilities.canEditCategory:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories/*', 'PUT'))
    if capabilities.canGetCategory:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'GET'))
    if capabilities.canAddAccount:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'POST'))
    if capabilities.canGetAccount:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'GET'))
    if capabilities.canEditAccount:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts/*', 'PUT'))
    if capabilities.canAddAccount:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/fiscals/*/account', 'POST'))
    if capabilities.canAddTax:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/tax', 'POST'))
    if capabilities.canAddScan:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/scan', 'POST'))
    if capabilities.canAddTransaction:
        casbin_roles.append((user_email, f'{company}/accounts/*', 'POST'))
    return casbin_roles
```

#### my try:

```
import functools
def permission_control(user_email,company):

    def partial(attribute_name):
        return functools.partial(getattr,capabilities,attribute_name)
        
    capabilities = Capabilities()
    permissions = ["canEditCompany","canDeleteCompany","canShareCompany","canAddFiscal","canAddCategory","canEditCategory","canGetCategory","canAddAccount","canGetAccount","canEditAccount","canAddAccount","canAddTax","canAddScan","canAddTransaction"]
    urls = [(company, 'PUT'),(company, 'Delete'),(f'{company}/sharing', 'Post'),(f'{company}/fiscal_year', 'POST'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'Post'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories/*', 'PUT'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'GET'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'POST'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'GET'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts/*', 'PUT'),(f'{company}/fiscals/*/account', 'POST'),(f'{company}/tax', 'POST'),(f'{company}/scan', 'POST'),(f'{company}/accounts/*', 'POST')]
    return [((user_email,) + url) for permission,url in zip(permissions,urls) if partial(permission)()]
```

#### question

- Any better, more pythonic way to achieve it?
- I think my code maybe even worse than the origin code, because it is hard to understand/maintain for my co-workers. Am I right?

Comment: This doesn't have enough contextual information. What are you actually trying to do? Where do those boolean values come from - are they hard-coded, or set from process environment variables, or what? Is the class instance expected to be immutable or will those permissions change over the lifetime of the object?

Comment: @Reinderien The boolean values come from database. The class instance should be immutable.

Comment: Please show the querying code

Comment: @Reinderien sorry i made a mistake, The class instance should be immutable, I already edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd dumb it down a little: no lambdas, no partials, no formatting (you only have suffixes and nothing else). Make your HTTP methods all-caps for uniformity, and also you can use a generator instead of a list comprehension. For your `Capabilities` you can accept boolean kwargs. Pre-register all of the possible capabilities in a constant dictionary roughly similar to Alex's `actions_dict` but with stronger typing.

Also note `permission_control` is a noun where method names should be verbs, i.e. `control_permissions` or, as I've proposed, `.evaluate()`

### Suggested

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple, Iterable

CapTuple = Tuple[
    str,  # email
    str,  # URL path
    str,  # method
]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Capability:
    name: str
    method: str
    path: str


CAPABILITIES = {
    name: Capability(name, method, path)
    for name, method, path in (
        ("canEditCompany",    'PUT',    ''),
        ("canDeleteCompany",  'DELETE', ''),
        ("canShareCompany",   'POST',   '/sharing'),
        ("canAddFiscal",      'POST',   '/fiscal_year'),
        ("canAddCategory",    'POST',   '/fiscals/*/categories'),
        ("canEditCategory",   'PUT',    '/fiscals/*/categories/*'),
        ("canGetCategory",    'GET',    '/fiscals/*/categories'),
        ("canAddAccount",     'POST',   '/fiscals/*/accounts'),
        ("canGetAccount",     'GET',    '/fiscals/*/accounts'),
        ("canEditAccount",    'PUT',    '/fiscals/*/accounts/*'),
        ("canAddAccount",     'POST',   '/fiscals/*/account'),
        ("canAddTax",         'POST',   '/tax'),
        ("canAddScan",        'POST',   '/scan'),
        ("canAddTransaction", 'POST',   '/accounts/*'),
    )
}


class Capabilities:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: bool):
        self.allowed: Tuple[Capability] = tuple(
            CAPABILITIES[name]
            for name, allowed in kwargs.items()
            if allowed
        )

    def evaluate(self, user_email: str, company: str) -> Iterable[CapTuple]:
        for cap in self.allowed:
            yield user_email, company + cap.path, cap.method


def test() -> None:
    caps = Capabilities(canAddAccount=True, canEditAccount=True, canDeleteCompany=False)
    for user_email, path, method in caps.evaluate('me@here.com', 'here_inc'):
        print(user_email, path, method)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 7):

I might be inclined to do something like this:

```
class Capabilities:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.canEditCompany = True
        self.canDeleteCompany = True
        self.canShareCompany = True
        self.canAddFiscal = True
        self.canAddCategory = True
        self.canEditCategory = True
        self.canGetCategory = True
        self.canAddAccount = True
        self.canGetAccount = True
        self.canEditAccount = True
        self.canAddTransaction = True
        self.canAddScan = True
        self.canAddTax = True

 actions_dict = {
    "canEditCompany":    lambda company: (company, 'PUT'),
    "canDeleteCompany":  lambda company: (company, 'Delete'),
    "canShareCompany":   lambda company: (f'{company}/sharing', 'Post'),
    "canAddFiscal":      lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscal_year', 'POST'),
    "canAddCategory":    lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'Post'),
    "canEditCategory":   lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories/*', 'PUT'),
    "canGetCategory":    lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/categories', 'GET'),
    "canAddAccount":     lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'POST'),
    "canGetAccount":     lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'GET'),
    "canEditAccount":    lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/accounts/*', 'PUT'),
    "canAddAccount":     lambda company: (f'{company}/fiscals/*/account', 'POST'),
    "canAddTax":         lambda company: (f'{company}/tax', 'POST'),
    "canAddScan":        lambda company: (f'{company}/scan', 'POST'),
    "canAddTransaction": lambda company: (f'{company}/accounts/*', 'POST')
}


def permission_control(user_email, company):
    capabilities = Capabilities()
    return [(user_email, *action(company)) for capability, action in actions_dict.items() if getattr(capabilities, capability)]
```

I agree that your code was in some ways less readable, but I think you were heading in the right direction by taking out that awful if-tree, which definitely counts as an anti-pattern in my opinion. I think keeping the input and the result together in a dictionary is much more readable than keeping them in two separate lists, as you had them — and by using `lambda` functions, we can construct the dict in the global namespace so it doesn't have to be made afresh every time the function is called, which is what your code was doing with your two lists.

---

EDIT: Following a suggestion in the comments, an even better solution would be to use `format-strings` rather than `lambdas`:

```
class Capabilities:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.canEditCompany = True
        self.canDeleteCompany = True
        self.canShareCompany = True
        self.canAddFiscal = True
        self.canAddCategory = True
        self.canEditCategory = True
        self.canGetCategory = True
        self.canAddAccount = True
        self.canGetAccount = True
        self.canEditAccount = True
        self.canAddTransaction = True
        self.canAddScan = True
        self.canAddTax = True

actions_dict = {
    "canEditCompany":    ('{}', 'PUT'),
    "canDeleteCompany":  ('{}', 'Delete'),
    "canShareCompany":   ('{}/sharing', 'Post'),
    "canAddFiscal":      ('{}/fiscal_year', 'POST'),
    "canAddCategory":    ('{}/fiscals/*/categories', 'Post'),
    "canEditCategory":   ('{}/fiscals/*/categories/*', 'PUT'),
    "canGetCategory":    ('{}/fiscals/*/categories', 'GET'),
    "canAddAccount":     ('{}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'POST'),
    "canGetAccount":     ('{}/fiscals/*/accounts', 'GET'),
    "canEditAccount":    ('{}/fiscals/*/accounts/*', 'PUT'),
    "canAddAccount":     ('{}/fiscals/*/account', 'POST'),
    "canAddTax":         ('{}/tax', 'POST'),
    "canAddScan":        ('{}/scan', 'POST'),
    "canAddTransaction": ('{}/accounts/*', 'POST')
}


def permission_control(user_email, company):
    capabilities = Capabilities()

    return [
        (user_email, url.format(company), method)
        for capability, (url, method) in actions_dict.items() 
        if getattr(capabilities, capability)
    ]
```

---

SECOND EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, the answer with format strings could be improved even more by pre-binding the `format` method of the format strings. This is slightly more performant, and constrains the strings to a single purpose.

I've also changed the data structure from a `str: tuple[str, str]` dictionary to a list of `NamedTuples`. A dictionary no longer made sense at this stage. NamedTuples aren't strictly necessary as opposed to tuples, but I think using them makes the intention of the code clearer and improves readability.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Callable, Literal

class Capabilities:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.canEditCompany = True
        self.canDeleteCompany = True
        self.canShareCompany = True
        self.canAddFiscal = True
        self.canAddCategory = True
        self.canEditCategory = True
        self.canGetCategory = True
        self.canAddAccount = True
        self.canGetAccount = True
        self.canEditAccount = True
        self.canAddTransaction = True
        self.canAddScan = True
        self.canAddTax = True


class CapabilityTuple(NamedTuple):
    capability: str
    url_factory: Callable[[str], str]

    # Any reason why some of these aren't all-uppercase in your question?
    # HTTP methods are usually all-uppercase
    method: Literal['PUT', 'Delete', 'POST', 'GET', 'Post'] 


actions_list = [
    CapabilityTuple(capability, url.format, method) for  capability, url, method in (
        ("canEditCompany",    '{}',                        'PUT'),
        ("canDeleteCompany",  '{}',                        'Delete'),
        ("canShareCompany",   '{}/sharing',                'Post'),
        ("canAddFiscal",      '{}/fiscal_year',            'POST'),
        ("canAddCategory",    '{}/fiscals/*/categories',   'Post'),
        ("canEditCategory",   '{}/fiscals/*/categories/*', 'PUT'),
        ("canGetCategory",    '{}/fiscals/*/categories',   'GET'),
        ("canAddAccount",     '{}/fiscals/*/accounts',     'POST'),
        ("canGetAccount",     '{}/fiscals/*/accounts',     'GET'),
        ("canEditAccount",    '{}/fiscals/*/accounts/*',   'PUT'),
        ("canAddAccount",     '{}/fiscals/*/account',      'POST'),
        ("canAddTax",         '{}/tax',                    'POST'),
        ("canAddScan",        '{}/scan',                   'POST'),
        ("canAddTransaction", '{}/accounts/*',             'POST')
    )
]


def permission_control(user_email, company):
    capabilities = Capabilities()

    return [
        (user_email, url_factory(company), method)
        for capability, url_factory, method in actions_list
        if getattr(capabilities, capability)
    ]
```

Comment: This is a useful answer. One alternative to consider: format strings, which can still be defined in advance, rather than lambdas, which are a bit heavier syntax-wise.

Comment: Oh, excellent idea! I've incorporated that into my answer — it makes it much cleaner

Comment: Bonus: pre-bind to the `.format` method of the format strings, to further constrain their purpose.

Comment: @Reinderien something like this? (Just using MyPy playground because it's convenient for code-sharing) https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=865b0c5f9e0a837bdecfd9a350e90fef

Comment: yep exactly. There will be a very very minor performance increase, but more importantly the string is constrained to only one purpose

Comment: Yeah, I like it, and would never have thought of it. Will edit it in.

Comment: The `Literal` is a good idea, but these are HTTP methods - you can stick with the upper-case strings

Comment: Yeah I know, was just sticking with the brief as it was provided in the question. Any reason why you went with frozen dataclasses rather than NamedTuples in your answer btw? I thought dataclasses were meant to be much less performant.

Comment: Quite honestly it's because I didn't know about the new(ish) `NamedTuple` inheritance-style definition. It's nice - thanks for showing that.

Comment: Yeah I like it much more — allows for type hints, and also makes it easy to extend the class and add your own methods — e.g. https://github.com/willmcgugan/textual/blob/main/src/textual/geometry.py. Always feels weird to me that it's in the typing module rather than collections.